# Deploy different versions of web-application

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, deployment, version, web-deployment

In this hypothetical scenario I have a web-app running on his 1st version, having around 1,000 active users.

I've just finished the 2nd version and would like to test with some users only, what would be the most patterned way to deliver this new version to those clients and have the rest of them still using the 1st?

Considering an application built using Express (Node.js) and deployed to AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your architecture, the details will vary (single ec2 instance, mutli instances, multiple with load balancer, multiple containers etc), but the general term for what you are looking to do is referred to as a 'blue green' deployment. Google that and you will get lots of hits, and then narrow down the results to one that matches the setup that is close to yours.

Here is one article, for example:

[Implementing Blue-Green Deployments with AWS](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/implementing-blue-green-deployments-aws)

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for A/B testing, which returned some results, but mostly related to mobile apps.